# mongodb replication with admin authentication error

Tags: mongodb, authentication, replication

I have three nodes of mongodb replication set
2 servers have the data and the third is an arbiter

> 54.83.20.44   :   27017   (primary)
>   54.197.243.55 :   40000   (secondary)
>   23.21.148.73  :   27017   (arbiter)

All things have been configured well with automatic failover.
BUT, I ignored any thing about authentication.
I can connect to the replset using "Robomongo" (desktop mongodb management tool) without username/password :( 
So I connected to admin database of primary member and ran this command:

> mongo
>   use admin 
>   db.addUser("username", "password");

Then, I restarted mongod process with --auth option

This is my log after restart:

> [rsBackgroundSync] replSet not trying to sync from 54.197.243.55:40000, it is vetoed for 8 more seconds
>   [rsHealthPoll] could not authenticate against 54.197.243.55:40000, { code: 18, ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth fails" }
>   [rsHealthPoll] replset info 54.197.243.55:40000 thinks that we are down

What can I do ? 
Adding username/password to all admin servers 

 or primary server only?

Comment: start all the server with --auth option. enable the internal authentication using the keyfile. follow the steps mentioned in this link https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/enable-internal-authentication/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should restart all the mongod instances with --auth option.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using replication authentication you must enable with keyfile authentication otherwise they will go out of sync state